# WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken returns error (but user exists!)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app, I'm trying to make a password forget page. In my POST, I check that the user related to the password is present

```
WebSecurity.UserExists(email)
```

and it returns **true**, but when I exectue

```
WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email, 10);
```

I'm getting this error

```
No account exists for *email*
```

For reference, I was following this tutorial: http://www.thecodingguys.net/tutorials/asp/webpages-membership-forgot-password-and-reset-password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved, somehow in [webpages_Membership] table it wasn't present the confirmation for the user.

Comment: Happened to me to. Check the data in the tables. While testing it is easy to have Userprofile entries without webpages_Membership entries.

Comment: But why? Surely we can't be expected to enter this manually every now and then...

Comment: Oooooh !  The IsConfirmed field equals 0 !

Answer (score 5):

If the user is not confirmed, the same error will be thrown. Took me a while to find out so this might help someone. Perhaps someone has a better way of doing it, because this is kind of hacky.

In my case, the client want to send the user a password by mail (I know....) and if the mail needs to be resent, a new password has to be genereated.

```
 private string ChangePasswordForNotConfirmedUser(string emailAdress)
    {
        var membership = _membershipRepository.GetByUserName(emailAdress);
        membership.IsConfirmed = true;
        _membershipRepository.Save(membership);
        var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(emailAdress);
        var password = Membership.GeneratePassword(GlobalSettings.PasswordLenght, GlobalSettings.PasswordNoAlphaChars);
        WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, password);
        membership.IsConfirmed = false;
        _membershipRepository.Save(membership);
        return password;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This solved the problem for me without thinking about anything else.

```
try
        {
            token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(username);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("No account"))
            { 
                string password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(6, 0);
                WebSecurity.CreateAccount(username, password);

            }
            token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(username);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case user account was not not confirmed in DB table webpages_Membership once I set isconfirmed=1 manually then its working fine